# Substitution of a line with another line in multiple files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have to substitute the content of lines from a file with another line (in the same position number 3) in multiple files. The problem looks like the following:

**Input1**

```
file.list <- list("a","b","c","d")
file.list <- list("d","e","f","g")
file.list <- list("h","i","l","m")
```

**Input2.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("z","g","h","s","i")
```

**Input3.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("s","p","q","r","m")
```

**Input4.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("x","k","s","e")
```

**Output of Input2.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("a","b","c","d")
```

**Output of Input3.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("d","e","f","g")
```

**Output of Input4.file**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("h","i","l","m")
```

> I have tried to do as follow:

```
filename='Input1'
for i in *.file; do #here i loop over the list of files
    while read p $filename; do #here i loop over the lines of Input1 file
        awk '{ if (NR == 3) print "$p"; else print $0}' $i > $i.test; ##here i substitute the line 1 in the files with the line that are in Input1 file
    done;
done
```

Am doing something wrong because the script is stopping without giving me any message. What am doing wrong? Any Idea?

Comment: It looks like you're redirecting the output of your `awk` command to a file. Why would you expect to see any messages?

Comment: Am outputting into a file because I want to create a new file if this is what you are asking. Or maybe there is something am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, that part makes sense to me. But if you output to a file then your output will be in the file - not on the screen. Did you check the files to see if your script worked?

Comment: the output file is not produced because the script is stopping but without giving me any error message.. something like this [7]+  Stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ gawk -i inplace '
    NR == FNR {repl[FNR] = $0; next} 
    FNR == 1  {filenum++} 
    FNR == 3  {$0 = repl[filenum]} 
    {print}
' Input1 Input{2,3,4}.file

$ cat Input2.file
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("a","b","c","d")

$ cat Input3.file
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("d","e","f","g")

$ cat Input4.file
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
file.list <- list("h","i","l","m")
```

---

Looking at your code:

1. you're replacing line 3 in each *.file with every line of Input1. You'll be left with the last line of Input1 as line 3 for every *.file.
2. `$p` cannot be expanded in your awk script, because it's in single quotes.

Try this:

```sh
exec 3<Input1   # set up file descriptor 3 to read from Input1 file
for f in *.file; do
    read -r -u 3 replacement   # read a line from fd 3  
    awk -v rep="$replacement" '{if (NR == 3) print rep; else print $0}' "$f" > "$f.test"
done
exec 3<&-       # close fd 3
```

Comment: I have used the correction of my script that you have proposed. Could you please explain how it works the "exec" variable that you have created? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `exec` is typically used to **replace** the current shell process with some other program. For instance `exec vim file` replaces the shell with an editor and when you exit the editor you don't go back to that shell because it's already gone. When you use exec **without** a program you can establish redirections in the current shell. Here I open file descriptor 3 to read from the Input 1 file. In a different language you might see `fh = open("Input1", "r")`

Answer (score 0):

> to substitute the content of lines from a file with another line

**`bash`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
i=0; for f in Input[2-4].file; do ((i++)); sed -n "${i}p" "Input1" > "$f"; done
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head Input[2-4].file
==> Input2.file <==
file.list <- list("a","b","c","d")

==> Input3.file <==
file.list <- list("d","e","f","g")

==> Input4.file <==
file.list <- list("h","i","l","m")
```

Comment: the line in which I Have to substitute the content in the Input2.file,Input3.file
, Input4.file is not the first but another number. I put the first here to simplify...

Comment: @fusion.slope, you should describe the actual conditions in the question to avoid confusion